# Class file not executing after setVisible(true)

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 on the Raspberry Pi 3 imported with Pi4J libraries.

The issue here is that the **Login.java** does not execute the written code inside **MainForm.java**'s `public static void main(String args[])`. However, the code in `MainForm.java` works whenever I run it directly by right clicking and selecting Run File but when I Run the whole Project, that is when the problem starts.

Here is the code for `Login.java`:

```
package Kiosk;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Login() {
        initComponents();

        jLabel_asterisk1.setVisible(false);
        jLabel_asterisk2.setVisible(false);
        jPanel1.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButton_login);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


    private void jButton_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        //asterisk required
        jLabel_asterisk1.setVisible(false);
        jLabel_asterisk2.setVisible(false);

        if(jTextField_username.getText().equals("")){

        jLabel_asterisk1.setVisible(true);

        }

        if(String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword()).equals("")){


            jLabel_asterisk2.setVisible(true);

        }

        else{


        Connection con = MyConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps;

            try {
                ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
                ps.setString(1, jTextField_username.getText());
                ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword()));

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if(rs.next()){

                    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
                    mf.setVisible(true);
                    mf.pack();
                    mf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                    MainForm.jLabel_welcome.setText(jTextField_username.getText());

                  this.dispose();   

                }

                else{

                    System.out.println("NO");
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });



    }

}
```

And for the `MainForm.java`:

```
package Kiosk;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioInterrupt;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioInterruptListener;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioInterruptEvent;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioUtil;

public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static volatile int pulses = 0;
    public static boolean display = true;

    public MainForm() {
        initComponents();


}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainForm().setVisible(true);

            }

        });

        //create listener //bill coin pulses
        GpioInterrupt.addListener(new GpioInterruptListener() {
            @Override
            public void pinStateChange(GpioInterruptEvent event) {

                if (event.getPin() == 0) {
                    if (event.getState() == false) {
                        pulses++;
                        display = true;
                    }

                }

                if (event.getPin() == 7) {
                    if (event.getState() == false) {
                        int bpulses = 0;
                        bpulses++;
                        pulses += bpulses * 10;
                        display = true;
                    }

                }

            }

        });

        //setup wiring pi
        if (Gpio.wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
            System.out.println("Setup Failed!");
            return;
        }

        //pins that will be used
        GpioUtil.export(7, GpioUtil.DIRECTION_IN);
        GpioUtil.export(0, GpioUtil.DIRECTION_IN);

        //edge state whether rising, falling or change
        GpioUtil.setEdgeDetection(7, GpioUtil.EDGE_FALLING);
        GpioUtil.setEdgeDetection(0, GpioUtil.EDGE_FALLING);

        //enabling input as a callback
        Gpio.pinMode(7, Gpio.INPUT);
        Gpio.pullUpDnControl(7, Gpio.PUD_UP);
        GpioInterrupt.enablePinStateChangeCallback(7);

        //enabling input as a callback
        Gpio.pinMode(0, Gpio.INPUT);
        Gpio.pullUpDnControl(0, Gpio.PUD_UP);
        GpioInterrupt.enablePinStateChangeCallback(0);

        //void loop
        for (;;) {
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
            if (display == true) {
                // System.out.println(pulses);
                jTextField_pulses.setText(String.valueOf(pulses));
                display = false;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You know what the `main(..)` method is meant to do, don't you? What makes you expect that the code in `Login` will call `MainForm`'s `main(...)`? If you don't know about how to use `main(...)` then you should grab some basic tutorial and read up on that.

Comment: Fixed it Thomas! I'm surely going to grab some basic tutorials. Hehe

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your problem is that your `main` method in the MainForm.java does not get called when using MainForm from Login.java.

The reason for that is that the `main` method is the entry point into your program not into your class. Thats why there is usually only one main method in a whole program. If you run Login.java you enter the program in the main method. However when calling MainForm you are already in the program so it does not call the main anymore. Equally when you run MainForm.java alone it needs to enter the program and will run the main.

Suggested solution:
Move your main from MainForm.java in a different method (something called initializePinListening or so) and call it.

Just for the record, there is such a thing as an entry point into a class. Would be the method `static{}`. But I would consider it bad code style to use that here.